# Wait for download completion in Python

Tags: python, download

I have a script, in which I must download a file, then use the file in the rest of the script. How can I stop a running script until the download is finished, then complete the running using a wait function?

```
    if erra:
        if os.path.isfile('/homes/biertank/Downloads/'+record.__dict__['qualifiers']['source'][0]+'-Clusters.gff')==False:

            webbrowser.open('http://napp.u-psud.fr/SqlGff.php?specie=355&SpecieName='+record.__dict__['qualifiers']['source'][0])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't control downloading with `webbrowser.open` module?

Use [`urllib.request.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) instead. It will block until download is done.

```
import urllib.request

...

url = ('http://napp.u-psud.fr/SqlGff.php?specie=355&SpecieName=' +
       record.__dict__['qualifiers']['source'][0])
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'local-filename-you-want')
```

If you use Pyhton 2.x, use [`urllib.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) instead.